# Which one is more Idiomatic in rust?

Tags: rust

Which is more idiomatic rust in this case,

```
//This is a C like a syntax where you can get the value at a location through *.
fn largest_i32(list: &[i32])-> i32{
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for item in list.iter(){
        if *item > largest{
            largest = *item;
        }

    };
    largest
}
```

or

```
//This syntax seems confusing to me, Is rust doing derefrecing iteself.
fn largest_i32(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

Comment: I'd say it is a matter of taste, personally I prefer the second syntax to because it lets you write `&` once instead of putting `*` all over the place.

Comment: [None](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max)

Comment: The official rust book has syntax mentioned in this question in the Generics/ traits chapter. Could you please help me with other resources from which I can get help ?

Comment: Also, your function should return `Option` (or `Result`) in case of empty vector, just like `.iter().max()` does.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, the most idiomatic solution would be

```rust
fn largest_i32(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    *list.iter().max().unwrap()
}
```

But if I had to choose between the two functions you wrote, I'd pick the second one.

> ```rust
> //This syntax seems confusing to me, Is rust doing derefrecing iteself.
> ```

`for` loops accept a **pattern**. `list.iter()` is an iterator over items with the type `&i32`, which is pattern-matched against `&item`, so `item` is [destructured](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-to-break-apart-values) into a `i32`. This has the same effect as dereferencing it.

Pattern matching is pervasive in Rust. You can read about all the places where patterns are allowed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html).